# How to pass an id to $.click in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code which

```
<a  href="#example" id="showtext">view text</a>

    $("#showtext").click (function () {
        $.post('/app/foo/bar/1', function (data){
           $("#msg").html(data);
        });
        $('#example').modal()
    });
```

When `view text` is clicked I'm making a post request out to `/app/foo/bar/1` and putting that data in a div with id `#msg`. All of this is working fine, however, now I would like to be able to pass different `ids` to this url, for example: `/app/foo/bar/2` or `/app/foo/bar/3` etc..

What is a good way to accomplish this?

One way I've thought of is to append the id to the attribute, like so:

```
<a href="#example" id="showtext${id}">view text</a>
```

and then parse out the `id` in jQuery using regex. However, this approach seems messy. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: what id are you trying to pass?

Comment: "now I would like to be" what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you need the `href` attribute left as it is, you can use a `data` attribute instead.

```
<a href="#example" id="showtext" data-url="/app/foo/bar/2">view text</a>
```

```js
$("#showtext").click(function() {
    $.post(
        $(this).data('url'), 
        function(data) {
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }
    );
    $('#example').modal()
});
```

Or, as I mentioned you could use the `href`:

```
<a href="/app/foo/bar/2" id="showtext">view text</a>
```

```js
$("#showtext").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the link being followed normally
    $.post(
        $(this).prop('href'), 
        function(data) {
            $("#msg").html(data);
        }
    );
    $('#example').modal()
});
```